# Using VLC to host a stream of an infinite video loop

Tags: video-streaming, vlc, rtsp

I want to offer a video stream from my pc with a VLC player trough a WIFI network to smartphones for regression testing. 
The video should automatically restart at the beginning after being finished on the smartphone.

I'm currently using rtsp as protocol and the loop option, but this is no mandatory. The problem is, that every time the video restarts a new rtsp handshake is necessary. Since most of the smartphone apps I tested don't support reconnecting the stream automatically after being finished, I want to have only one handshake being valid all over the time.

```
vlc mypath\myvideo.mp4 sout=#transcode{vcodec=h264,acodec=none}:rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8554/} --loop
```

Thank you

Comment: Is possible that the same problem prevent video from looping in a web browser?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to use `--sout-keep` which keeps the stream output open (disabled by default)

and use `gather:std` and transcode option if the files use different encoding so that there wouldn't be any noticeable interruption on input change.

see:

1: https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Streaming_HowTo/Command_Line_Examples/#Keeping_the_stream_open

2: https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Modules/gather/

Comment: I'm trying to do that, but ffmpeg -I still detects end of file. my command is: cvlc --no-audio --loop --demux 'avformat' --avformat-format=mjpeg images-fifo --fps-fps 5 --mjpeg-fps 5 --sout-transcode-fps 5 --sout-keep --sout '#standard{access=http{mime="multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary=7b3cc56e5f51db803f790dad720ed50a"},mux=mpjpeg,dst='":8084/video.mjpeg}" vlc://pause:10 ---- any ideas?

Answer (score 10):

Thank you freeforall tousez!

`The gather:std` setting worked great for me.
Below is my command line string for RTSP with a playlist.

```
cvlc --random --loop /var/www/html/files/test.xspf :sout=#gather:rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8554/} :network-caching=1500 :sout-all :sout-keep
```

This streams a playlist of videos randomly in a never ending loop.
I hope this will help others.

Comment: yep it helped me too

Comment: I'm trying to use this command in an HTTP source: cvlc --loop "http://192.168.1.51/cgi-bin/snapshot.cgi?d=1&q=0&chn=0&u=admin&p=test" :sout=#gather:rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8554/} :network-caching=1500 :sout-all :sout-keep ---- but then trying to read it, I see a bunch of "[rtsp @ 0xc291c0] Missed previous RTP Marker" and ffmpeg can't read the rtsp stream. Any ideas?